# Can Mac OS X use a 1400x1050 projector's native resolution?

Tags: display, resolution, projector

I'm trying to connect my MacBook Pro to a Canon LCD projector with a native resolution of 1400x1050.

The maximum 4:3 resolution that Mac OS X offers is 800x600. With the SwitchResX utility I've managed to get it to display at 1024x768, but no higher without using widescreen resolutions. In Windows running via Bootcamp I can use the projector's full native resolution (so I know it isn't a hardware issue), and projected images look a whole lot better.

Is running Windows my only option if I want to get the best out of a projector like that? Or is there some way of getting it working properly with Mac OS X?